# Probability that $xy \le 1$ and $x/y \ge 2$

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

I am new to probability and statistics so please bear with me.

> Let $x$,$y$ be any real numbers in the interval [$0,2$]. What is the probability that $xy \le 1$ and $x/y \ge 2$?

Usually I would write what I've got so far, but I don't even know where to begin with this problem.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ real or integer numbers?

Comment: any real numbers in that range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The probability space $[0,2]\times[0,2]$ can be seen as a $2\times 2$ square with opposite corners at $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$. Its area is $4$. So given a region $R$ in this square, the probability that a random point $(x,y)$ is in $R$ is simply the area of $R$ divided by $4$.

So now you just have to figure out the area of the region where $xy\le 1$ and $x/y\ge 2$. Start by drawing a graph of the curves $y=1/x$ and $y=x/2$.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed yet not overdone answer. It let me think for myself.